# change the "default output" of a TypeSript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to change the "default output" of a TypeSript class. Is there any possibility to output a property of a class wenn calling it without "class."?

```
class Observer {
    character: Character;

    constructor(_character: Character) {
        this.character = Vue.Observer(_character);
    }
}

class Character {
    data: number;
    
    constructor(_data: number) {
        this.data = _data;
    }
}

console.log(new Observer(new Character(123)).data) // what I want it to output is 123 (the output of new Observer(new Character(123)).charactr.data)
```

I hope you can see what I want to do.

Comment: "I hope you can see what I want to do" yes but not why, that is generally thought to be a bad idea... overriding the default return value (at least in JS) will basically mean that your class instance is thrown away. Typescript does not have nominal typing, so you can't even use it to create a special type of e.g. number like you can in some languages. But if you really can't resist, it [does work](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PWPAdhALgE4Cuw+8h0AFAJQrqaOECm+xhO0A5AGaJcBuBhgC+qMamx580PkgC80HMwDucRLSFA)

Comment: @JaredSmith is it a bad idea to provide a custom `toString` member though? I can certainly see how specifying one that returns `123` could be a bad idea...

Comment: @AluanHaddad of course not but I was reading the question literally. And as I'm sure you know console.log does not call `toString`.

Comment: we want to create an observer for a custom class. So we want to use "new Oberserver(new Character())" just like a normal Character instance. It would be nice to write obeserver.characterFunction instead of observer.character.charcterfunction

Comment: @Caesar0815 sorry that doesn't really make sense how you've described it. Can you edit it in to your question with some example code?

Comment: @Caesar0815 that has nothing to do with what you've asked. It sounds like you want a proxy of some kind

Comment: @Caesar0815 it's fine, that's a good instinct it just went wrong in this case. I don't think there's any way to do what you're trying to do here though. You can override the return value of a constructor (as in my link above) but then you just get the thing rather than an instance. You can't change the behavior of `console.log` in any way that I know of, although there may be a non-portable way in specific implementations.

Comment: Read about javascript object proxies https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy